# Restructure lists into dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Given the following arrays:

```
fields1 = [ 'A1', 'B1', 'C1']
fields2 = [ 'A2', 'B2', 'C2']
array = [fields1, fields2, ...., fieldsN]
```

I need to reorganize the data programmatically into the following object:

```
the_fields = {
       'column1' : ['A1', 'A2'],
       'column2' : ['B1', 'B2'],
       'column3' : ['C1', 'C2']}
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: These are called lists and dicts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**
`zip`
Use `zip`ped packing inside a dict comprehension.

```
fields = [fields1, fields2, ...., fieldsN]
{'column{}'.format(i) : list(v) for i, v in enumerate(zip(*fields), 1)}
```

```
{
   'column1' : ['A1', 'A2'],
   'column2' : ['B1', 'B2'],
   'column3' : ['C1', 'C2']   
}
```

---

**Option 2**
`pd.DataFrame.to_dict`
This option uses the pandas API

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(fields).rename(
    columns=lambda x: 'column{}'.format(x + 1)
).to_dict(orient='list')
```

```
{
   'column1' : ['A1', 'A2'],
   'column2' : ['B1', 'B2'],
   'column3' : ['C1', 'C2']   
}
```